# Javascript read JSON from REST server with status updates

Tags: javascript, rest

I need to read a large JSON file from a REST server, and want to provide status updates as I read it (ie 28% downloaded...). Are there any examples on how best to do this?

I assume I need to put the total size of the JSON in the beginning of the JSON file so I know the total, and then just get a status callback on each block read from the server.

thanks - dave

Comment: Is this being done with Ajax? Are you using any libraries, such as jQuery? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nullability I have not tried anything yet. I am very new to javascript and so I figured a random example I find via google could be great... or awful. And I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

With Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhrFields: {
    onprogress: function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
           console.log(e.loaded / e.total * 100 + '%');
        }
    }
},
success: function (response) {
   //do some
}
});
```

Comment: thank you - give me a day to implement/test and then I'll check this.